# Flutter Google maps add and remove markers after map is rendered

Tags: flutter, google-maps, render, markers

Hi I have trouble understanding how I can add markers (and delete old ones) to the map after the map is created. My app have a stacked menu and the user should be able to click on buttons to see other markers. So somehow I need to get the clicks to render new markers on the map, and I dont want to rerender the whole map if its possible to not. I know there is an onTap property in the GoogleMaps class but I cannot seem to get it to work. Any ideas would be much appreciated. Also I have separated the markers in a different class that is imported. This is my relevant code:

UPDATE TO MY CODE!!
The strange thing is that it works when I use a ternary operator on the markers argument as seen below in the code but this is not enough I want more to choose from. For example I want to be able to use six bool flags that should set different markers from different markers Sets (marker.getSpecialMarker, getBlackMarker for example). Anyone of you know how to do this please?

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                menuIsVisible = !menuIsVisible;
                print(menuIsVisible.toString());
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        elevation: 1,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Title',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              letterSpacing: 2.0,
              fontSize: 40,
              fontFamily: 'Bebas Neue'),
        ),
body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          FutureBuilder<bool>(
              //If _prepareWidget returns true we are good to go and the icons are not null
              future: marker.prepareWidget(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return GoogleMapWidget(

                      initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
                      controller: controller,
                      
                      markers: markers: _saucerMarkers!
                    ? marker.getGoldMarkers()
                    : marker.getBlackMarkers(),);
                  //onTap: () {}
                  //   setState(() {
                  //     marker.addMarkersBlack();
                  //   });
                  // });

                } else {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              }),

Positioned(
              left: 15.0,
              child: Visibility(
                visible: menuIsVisible,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.change_circle_outlined,
                        color: changeIconColor,
                        size: 35.0,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (changeIconColor == Color(0xff050505)) {
                            changeIconColor = Color(0xffebc030);
                            changeIconColorU = Color(0xff050505);
                          } else {
                            changeIconColor = Color(0xff050505);
                            changeIconColorU = Color(0xffebc030);
                          }
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Image.asset(
                        'images/image1.png',
                        color: changeIconColorU,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        changeIconColorU == Color(0xff050505)
                            ? selectedShape = iconShapeColor.UBlack
                            : selectedShape = iconShapeColor.UGold;
                        print(selectedShape);
                        
                      },
                    ),
                    
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Image.asset(
                        'images/image2.png',
                        color: changeIconColorU,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        changeIconColorU == Color(0xff050505)
                            ? selectedShape = iconShapeColor.TBlack
                            : selectedShape = iconShapeColor.TGold;
                        print(selectedShape);
                      },
                    ),



class GoogleMapWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const GoogleMapWidget(
      {Key? key,
      required CameraPosition initialCameraPosition,
      required this.controller,
      this.customIcon,
      this.markers,
      this.onTap})
      : _initialCameraPosition = initialCameraPosition,
        super(key: key);

  final CameraPosition _initialCameraPosition;
  final controller;
  final BitmapDescriptor? customIcon;
  final markers;
  final onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GoogleMap(
      myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
      zoomControlsEnabled: false,
      initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
      onMapCreated: controller!,
      markers: markers,
      onTap: onTap,

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried converting your `GoogleMap` to a `StatefulWidget`, and use `setState` to update markers? I don't think there is a way to update the markers without rebuilding the map widget.

Comment: Exactly as @PeterKoltai says. You do need to rebuild the `GoogleMap` widget with a new set of markers for them to show up or change. Just make sure to keep the previously used map controller. In your case, you're calling `setState()` from the Scaffold, so you're rebuilding the whole Scaffold anyway... may I suggest you restructure a little so only your Map and Buttons rebuild, instead of the whole thing.

Comment: If I change to this:

Comment: If I change it to the code below it works with two options but I need to have more options. The mMarkers variable is a bool and I have other bools that lead to other options but I dont know how to implement this? If I make a function with a switch just to try it I get 'Null' is not a subtype of type Set<Marker>
I also tried as you suggested  to make googlemapwidget a stateful widget but same error. 



markers: _mMarkers!
                       ? marker.getGoldMarkers()
                       : marker.getBlackMarkers());

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved my problem!! I will just put the relevant code here. I created a new Set _markerChoice that I copied all from respective marker set that I got from my marker-screen. As you can see below and then I just put that Set in the marker argument (with an if null that it will be from the start). When click on the respective icon I now get black markers or the gold markers and this can be used on more sorts of markers as well: I hope you get the concept even though im not to good at explaining :)

..........................................................

```
markers: markers: **_markerChoice ??
                          marker.getGoldMarkers());**

                } else {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              }),

Positioned(
              left: 15.0,
              child: Visibility(
                visible: menuIsVisible,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.change_circle_outlined,
                        color: changeIconColor,
                        size: 35.0,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (changeIconColor == Color(0xff050505)) {
                            changeIconColor = Color(0xffebc030);
                            changeIconColorU = Color(0xff050505);
                          } else {
                            changeIconColor = Color(0xff050505);
                            changeIconColorU = Color(0xffebc030);
                          }
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Image.asset(
                        'images/image1.png',
                        color: changeIconColorU,
                      ),
                       onPressed: () {
                        **if (changeIconColorU == Color(0xff050505)) {
                          _markerChoice!.clear();
                          selectedShape = iconShapeColor.Black;
                          changeIconColorU = Color(0xffebc030);
                          for (Marker m in marker.getBlackMarkers()) {
                            _markerChoice!.add(m);
                          }
                        } else {
                          _markerChoice!.clear();
                          selectedShape = iconShapeColor.Gold;
                          changeIconColorU = Color(0xff050505);
                          for (Marker m in marker.getGoldMarkers()) {
                            _markerChoice!.add(m);**
                          }
                        }
                        print(selectedShape);
                        
                      },
                    ),
                    
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Image.asset(
                        'images/image2.png',
                        color: changeIconColorU,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        changeIconColorU == Color(0xff050505)
                            ? selectedShape = iconShapeColor.TBlack
                            : selectedShape = iconShapeColor.TGold;
                        print(selectedShape);
                      },
                    ),
```

.................................................................